# Using Partial causes: A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'

Tags: typescript

I have some routes defined as following:

```
export const Route = {
  HOME: 'home',
  LOGIN: 'login',
  STUDIES: 'studies',
} as const;
```

And I want to create a const that should have keys as the keys from the `Route` constant:

```
export const RoutesPermissions: RoutesPermissionsType = {
  STUDIES: 'STUDIES',
} as const;
```

`HOME` and `LOGIN` routes are not mandatory so I only defined `STUDIES`.

My `RoutesPermissionsType` is defined as following:

```
export type RoutesPermissionsType = Partial<{
  [P in keyof typeof Route]: string;
}>;
```

And then I want to create another object that has a key as the key of `RoutesPermissions` and a value as boolean:

```
export const ROUTES_PERMISSIONS: PermissionsType = {
  [RoutesPermissions.STUDIES]: true,
};
```

`PermissionsType` is defined as following:

```
export type PermissionsType = Partial<{
  [P in keyof typeof RoutesPermissions]: boolean;
}>;
```

I used `Partial` since I dont want to define all the `RoutesPermissions` keys.

The problem I'm facing is that in the `ROUTES_PERMISSIONS` I have this typescript error:

```
(property) STUDIES?: string | undefined
A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'
```

And here is the link to the ts playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBKECuNgGcAKwUAtgJa66kQB2uAKsqgLxz4CGspbANgDwDeAWABQcOAG18cUtTgBrYIggAzBIxXosOALoAuOLhhQZAcwDcIgL4A+C8NCRYalKyJkKVWgxct2nHgIiYpLSsgpKqkgoGhjYeIQk5JQ0uHpwAEYQENzAbNR2NnYiDtDwAMYp8LE4cCxConAAEgDyALIAovoA5AAWEMTAXQA0QXAAMs0A4gCSAHLd3BAmMsOjAMp0AKoAItPta92GmAAmpHirwpZwbLhwFbQwRfbgpXeVmnEEbkmeuPrV8W+HhS3mYcHqYg2Oz2BzgXShu32FyuNzeDyeJSc90M6Gamzo+wA+vh2mhWtM1mtps1ZrCEu5kl5GLVwaNxACvolgbQAHQImFpIyYYAjS52IA

how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type annotation to `satisfies` (TS 4.9+):

```
export const RoutesPermissions = {
  STUDIES: 'STUDIES',
} as const satisfies RoutesPermissionsType;
```

then you won't lose the type information that `RoutesPermissions.STUDIES` exists.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBKECuNgGcAKwUAtgJa66kQB2uAKsqgLxz4CGspbANgDwDeAWABQcOAG18cUtTgBrYIggAzBIxXosOALoAuOLhhQZAcwDcIgL4A+C8NCRYalKyJkKVWgxct2nHgIiYpLSsgpKqkgoGhjYeIQk5JQ0uHpwAEYQENzAbNR2NnYiDtDwAMYp8LE4cCxConAAEgDyALIAovoA5AAWEMTAXQA0QXAAMs0A4gCSAHLd3BAmMsOjAMp0AKoAItPta92GmAAmpHirwpZwbLhwFbQwRfbgpXeVmnEEbkmet3XrW12+26Gx2ezWFyuNzeDwMbBg5GUZ1u1Xi3w8KW8wCeJSc90M6Gamzo+wA+vh2mhWtM1mtps1ZgdXIkMV5GLU4PVgqivizkrQAHSgoFrNJGTDAEaXOxAA)